# SYMFONY3 upload files without entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing a really simple test site, I have images in one of my project's folder, and I simply display them on the site.
I don't have any entities or database interactions so no form either.

Now, I would like to upload a file in the most simple way. :

Choose a file -> move it in my project's images folder.

I had a look on the doctrine tutorial but it's for entity images.

Is it possible ? Many thanks.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704738/symfony2-simple-file-upload-edit-without-entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't conflate entities with forms.  Symfony forms work fine with just arrays.

The suggested link in the comments is something I posted a few years ago.  But it is a bit confusing.

In any event, here is the simplest way I know to upload a file.  No Symfony forms or Doctrine entities required.

Lets assume you have generated an html form that looks like:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

So the user selects a file and pushed the button.  Your upload controller action kicks off.  And if you don't know how to create either the form html or link it to a controller action then you really need to spend more time on the basics.

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{
    // See if posted
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        // Pull the uploaded file information
        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $request->files->get('file');

        // And now you have access to assorted file info such as
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
```

Comment: Quick note: shouldn't it be `if ($request->isMethod('POST'))...` ?

Comment: @RomainBruckert Wow.  Good eye.  Maybe I left that as an exercise?  In any event.  It is fixed.